# How To submit form with ajax that was already loaded with ajax, without reload the current page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm struggling with this problem for about week, What I need to do, Is submit form with ajax, That was already loaded with ajax, I have tried many solutions but nothing work, So if someone know, the right approach, I will be appreciated, 
And Thank advanced.

**This is my code :**

```
<form class="w3-container" method="POST" action="forms-submitting" id="SignIN">
        <p>
        <label><b> إسم المستخذم </b></label>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" name="user_name">
        </p>
        <p>
        <label><b> كلمة المرور <b></label>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="password" name="pass_word">
        </p>
        <p>
            <button type="submit" class="w3-button w3-text-blue"> تسجيل الدخول </button>
        </p>
</form>
```

And this is my ajax code:

```
$("#SignIN").submit(function(e) {
  var url = "forms-handle.php";
  $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: $("#SignIN").serialize(),
       success: function(data)
       {
           alert(data); 
       }
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: the form is loaded by ajax ? if that it is , it could be that your js code that submits the form doesn't find the "#SignIN" id .

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not using the regular submit you could change your button to `button` type and attach click event to this button like :

```
<button type="button" id="login" class="w3-button w3-text-blue"> تسجيل الدخول </button>

$('body').on('click', '#login', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "forms-handle.php",
       data: $("#SignIN").serialize(),
       success: function(data)
       {
           alert(data); 
       }
  });
});
```

**NOTE :** Since the `form` is loaded dynamically you should use event delegation **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok please check you browser console for any errors .. check also the network tab to see if the request was sent or not..

Comment: I check the network tab the request was not sent, and there is no errors in the browser console.